# Is the stack / heap memory model optional?

Tags: memory-management, fortran, stack, llvm, heap-memory

I can't understand if the use of a stack/heap memory model is a decision for the programmer, or whether it is up to the OS and the programmer has no choice but to work with it.

For example, can stack-less languages like Fortran77 operate across modern platforms still using a stack-less, array based memory model? Or instead, do modern Fortran compilers have to translate the array memory model to a stack/heap memory model? (I can't find much documentation on Fortran memory management.)

If the memory model is a decision for the programmer, why does everything I encounter seem to implicitly assume the stack/heap model is the only option? For example, LLVM operates with stack frames, and I can't find any documentation on managing memory any other way. All languages built on LLVM, even functional languages, must then adopt the stack/heap model when alternative models may be better suited.

If the memory model is a decision for the OS, does this mean writing a program that uses a custom memory model requires writing a custom OS? For example, do I need a custom OS if I want to run a Fortran program that uses the array based memory model Fortran was designed around?

If the answer depends on the OS, please give some comparisons across different OSs.

Comment: the Software Engineering StackExchange site might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @jdigital when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: I used Fortran77 for several years, how is it stack-less? It has a program stack for sure and memory can be allocated on the stack. Dynamic memory allocation (heap) is not available (at least if I am remembering correctly). Can you give a more concrete example of the question?

Comment: @linuxuser27: My understand is that ancient FORTRAN compilers statically allocated per-function buffer areas for parameter passing and local variables in place of dynamic stack allocation, thereby disallowing recursion. Though this was due to limitations of the computer architecture which the compiler targeted rather than any particular design intention of the language. These days efficient stack and pointer support is ubiquitous on desktop architectures, but even some modern embedded C compilers still employ overlay schemes for performance on limited architectures (8051, say).

Comment: RECURSIVE became a standard feature of Fortran with f90.  Some f77 compilers already had it as a default.  The most widely used current Fortran compilers have compile switches to choose whether dynamic allocation is on stack or heap, so it is easy to try both ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack and heap have nothing *directly* to do with Fortran, the standard says nothing about them at all. Similarly C, at least to C89, my knowledge is less good after that. Rather the compiler has to translate the language features as defined by the standard onto an underlying memory model. That memory model is the choice of the compiler implementer, but it is usually most convenient to use whatever features the target OS gives you. Hence you often see stacks and heaps, but at least as far as Fortran and C are concerned that has nothing to do with the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some misconceptions. First of all, FORTRAN implementations generally (always in practice?) use a stack. Classic FORTRAN may not allocate variables on the stack but it has to use the stack to make procedure calls. Even with FORTRAN implementations that use static argument frames, they still create stack frames.

The heap is just memory that is managed as allow random allocations and dealloations of memory. Some programming languages use the heap implicitly, such as to manage dynamic strings and arrays (e.g. BASIC). Other programming languages allow the programmer to use the heap but do not require it (e.g. C). Some programming languages do not generally use the heap at all for programmer accessible constructs (e.g. Cobol, classic FORTRAN).

Comment: Your statement is highly questionable. A compiler for the language that does not allow recursion and a dynamic memory allocation (e.g., standard FORTRAN-77) can calculate function call memory requirements at compile time. Stack was not necessary.